# What is the most efficient strategy to build a balanced diet for muscle gains?

Tags: diet, calories, muscle-gain

I've read in many articles regarding the usual macro division in a diet for those which train that is the 40% of the calories from proteins, 40% from carbs and 20% from fats; but, in others, I can see people saying that you don´t need to count calories once you fit 2.2~3g of protein per body/kg you have, 2~4g of carbs and 1g of fats per body/kg you have.

The first one you have to increase proteins/carbs to reach out the calories count. The second one, the calories count is increased by the high fat.

So, what to count then... calories or grams?

Comment: Are you a beginner? If that is the case its not necessary you worry about this. Just train using a full body program and you will be fine.

Comment: @MuntasirAlam, not, I´m not exactly a beginner! Trainning and diet for 3 years so far

Comment: I see. If thats the case you might want to measure your food and count your calories for a week or two and then check your weight. After that you could re-adjust accordingly. After a while you will probably just get a feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

Below are a few links that you may find useful when it comes to deciding what kinda nutrition suits you.

http://www.musclebuildingfoodshq.com/the-best-bodybuilding-diet-for-muscle-building/
http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/13-arnold-schwarzenegger-approved-nutrition-tips.html

Note: just use the above as reference, not as  a rule, as every individual is different so are the needs based on body-type , weight and size, but what applies as a generic thing is, to keep supplying your body with constant feeding on energy. You can't gain muscles magically out of noting, so eating right is what you need to do. Also, try out different nutrition techniques see what works the best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that each body is different and some diet may work for one and not for another, but I'm looking for answers based on their own experience using one or another pros/cons. Liked the links anyway.